# Python JSON variables not being accepted

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to save the variables from a JSON string to be used as settings for a different function, sadly though, they are not being accepted as good as I wanted. Here's what's cooking;

The JSON string comes through MQTT as so:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        data = json.loads(msg.payload)
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
        camera.sharpness = data['sharpness']
        camera.contrast = data['contrast']
```

However, when it gets the message, it errors out:

```
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py",
> line 2392, in _set_sharpness
>     "Invalid sharpness value: %d (valid range -100..100)" % value) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not unicode
```

Any idea why? I don't really know why it comes up with %d while when I print the data:

```
print data['sharpness']
>>> 50
```

It comes out as a number...

Any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: Your JSON contains a string value (`"50"`), not a number.

Comment: what is the result of `print type(data['sharpness'])`?

Comment: `print type(data['sharpness'])`. You may (or may not) be surprised.

Comment: Did you try to explicityl typecast it? From the `print` result, you can't tell whether it is a number or a string -- check types to be sure.

Comment: Or instead of using print, just type `>>> data['sharpness']`.

Comment: `camera.sharpness = int(data['sharpness'])` should do

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your values with `int` as these are in `unicode` format

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        data = json.loads(msg.payload)
        camera = picamera.PiCamera()
        camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
        camera.sharpness = int(data['sharpness'])
        camera.contrast = int(data['contrast'])
```